# multivariable calculus unusual integration formula

Tags: multivariable-calculus, fluid-dynamics, simulation

I was reading a book and he was measuring the rate of change of the volume of the fluid by the below integration formula :

$\frac { d }{ dt } volume(\Omega )=\iint _{ \partial \Omega  } \overrightarrow { u } .\hat { n }$

It is the first time I see an integration like this ! 
Where is the differential operator for example (dt , dx ..etx) ?

What does it mean to integrate over the boundary $\partial \Omega$ ?

What does it mean to integrate the dot product of the velocity and the normal component $\hat {n}$ ?

I don't understand it at all so please help me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really believe $\vec{u}$ is understood to be the velocity vector. That was $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{n}$ is calculating the fluid moving in the direction normal to the surface. Think of the example where fluid flows at an angle $\theta$ relative to your surface $S$. If we allow $\vec{u}$ to be constant (i.e the velocity vector) then the black of water is a parallelepiped of volume $A \|\vec{u}_0\| \cos \theta$. If $\vec{n}$ is a vector normal to $S$ of length equal to the area of $A$, then we can write;

$$\textrm{Flow rate} = A \|\vec{u}_0\| \cos \theta = \vec{u_0} \cdot \vec{n}$$

[image]

In general the velocity field $\vec{u}$ is not constant and the surface $S$ may be curved. To compute the flow rate, we first parametrize $S$ using $G(u,v)$ and consider a small rectangle of size $\nabla u \times \nabla v$ that is mapped to a small patch $S_0$ of $S$. For any sample point $G(u_0,v_0)$ in $S_0$, the vector $\vec{n}(u_0,v_0) \nabla u \nabla v$ is a normal vector of length approximately equal to the area of $S_0$. The patch is nearly rectangular so we have;

$$\textrm{Flow rate through} \ S_0 \approx \vec{u}(u_0,v_0) \cdot \vec{n}(u_0,v_0) \nabla u \nabla v$$

[image]
$$\\$$

Now if we sum up the flow over all the patches we have;

$$\\$$

$$\textrm{Flow rate through S} = \iint_S \vec{u} \cdot d\vec{S} = \iint_D \vec{u}(x,y) \cdot \vec{n}(x,y) \ dA$$

Comment: where is dS in the forumla I wrote in the question :3

Comment: A common gesture in mathematics is that, it is understood that the reader knows the mind of the write. It was just dropped here, just as one would write $\int f(x) \ dx = \int f\  dx = \int f$.

Comment: That u * n is calculating the fluid moving in the direction normal to the surface ??

What does it mean ? what do u mean by calculating fluid !! it is unusual quantity to me :D

Comment: Think of when you were doing flux calculations in a vector field. To calculate the fluid passing through or into a surface, you needed to establish a unified notion of outside to inside (coming in) or inside to outside (leaving out). For this reason we took $\textbf{F} \cdot \vec{n}$ which is the projection of $\text{F}$ onto $\vec{n}$. i.e the integral would compute the part which is in the direction of the normal vector.

Comment: so $\partial \Omega$ is the boundaries ? how ?

Comment: so u . n is calculating how much the fluid lost of volume ??

Comment: This all depended on whether you choose to orient the boundary with the outward or inward pointing normal. Is this making sense?

Comment: why will n have length equal to the area ?

Comment: What is the big title of this ? Isn't there any tutorials or videos ?

Comment: I have notes to this on my webpage here:https://faraadarmwoodblog.wordpress.com/teaching-2/, read 16.4,16.5. We can open a chat room later if you still have questions.

Comment: tell me what is the subject that includes all of this ?

Comment: The big subject: Multivariable Calculus, the small subsection: surface integrals.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to understand the physics for which this calculus was invented.  Here is an excellent source, from a brilliant lecturer (and a physics Nobel laureate):
http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_03.html